# jquery popup message box working in the while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a popup message box working in the while loop, but in the popup address field the same address is shown for all entries.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Html Jquery Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(e) { 
        $('#modal').reveal({ 
            animation: 'fade',                   
            animationspeed: 600,                       
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,              
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'   
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>

<table>
$query1=mysql_query("select * from customers order by id desc");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['firstname']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['lastname']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['dob']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['email']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><a href="#" class="button">Address</a></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['phone']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['country']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['city']; ?></div></td>
</tr>


<Popup Start> 

<div id="modal">
<div id="heading">
Sign Up! Customer's Address
</div>
<div id="content">
<p><?php echo $row1['address']; ?></p>
</div>
</div>

<Popup End>

<?php }?>
</table>
```

**Popup Showing same address in every row of the table**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using the same ID in the popup for each div. Therefore no matter what code you call to open the popup, it will always open the first popup. You need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function(e) { 
        id = $(this).attr('id').substr(3);
        //alert(id); //uncomment this line to check ID's are coming through fine.
        $('#modal' + id).reveal({ 
            animation: 'fade',                   
            animationspeed: 600,                       
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,              
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'   
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>

<table>
<?php
$i = 0;
$query1=mysql_query("select * from customers order by id desc");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['firstname']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['lastname']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['dob']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['email']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><a href="#" id="btn<?php echo $i; ?>" class="button">Address</a></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['phone']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['country']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['city']; ?></div></td>
</tr>


<Popup Start> 

<div class="modal" id="modal<?php echo $i++; ?>">
<div class="heading">
Sign Up! Customer's Address
</div>
<div class="content">
<p><?php echo $row1['address']; ?></p>
</div>
</div>

<Popup End>

<?php }?>
</table>
```

Note the change of the other div's from ID to Class. You should only use an ID once on a page. If you reuse something more than once it should be a Class.

Also you mislabelled your tags. This is a Javascript / HTML issue, not a PHP one.

Comment: It's not tested and I'll need a little more info other than it's not working before I can help. Are you getting any error messages in Firebug? What is it doing, if anything at all?

Don't forget once you change the ID's to classes you'll need to update your css.

I also forgot to increment the variable $i, I've update the code above, try again.

Comment: if i use id instead of class then button won't open popup message box

Comment: I just noticed you had $('#button'), but button is a class. You need $('.button').click(); Change that for one. If that still doesn't work then try alert(id); after id = to make sure that the correct id is being selected. After that check to make sure that the code is properly outputting all the different modals with the numbers after them.

Comment: I've been modifying my script above each time. I've even added in the alert for you now, but tbh you should be able to do basic debugging yourself.