# jquery dialog in PHP while loop

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop, dialog

The following code works fine just for the button in the very first row of the table. The buttons of the other automatically generated rows don't open any dialog. I guess the problem is that I am not assigning a different `id` to each button. How can I do that? I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916127/jquery-popup-message-box-working-in-the-while-loop) but nothing worked.

```
<table class="table-hovered">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-left big">TITOLO</th>
        <th class="text-centered" align="center">
            <img src="img/w.png" width="35" height="35" title="wikipedia" align="middle"><br>
            wikipedia
        </th>
    </tr>
    <? while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    { ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-left"><?=$objResult["titolo"];?></td>
            <td class="text-centered">
                <button id="trigger" class="btn">definizione</button>
                <div id="dialog" style="display: none;" title="definizione">
                    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="480" height="380" src="def.php?titolo=<?=$objResult['titolo'];?>"></iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
            <script>
                $("#trigger").click(function() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                });

                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    position: 'center' ,
                    title: 'definizione',
                    draggable: true,
                    width: 500,
                    height: 400, 
                    resizable: true,
                    modal: true,
                    show: 'slide',
                    hide: 'fade'
                });
            </script>
        </tr>
    <?  } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Since you are doing a loop, you have `n` number of `<button id="trigger">` and `n` number of `<div id="dialog">`. Since `id`s are supposed to be unique, then jQuery(/javascript) will only find and bind to the first one. You need to make those `id`s unique, or change them to a class `<button class="trigger">` / `<div class="dialog">` and `$(".trigger").click(function() {$(".dialog").dialog("open"); });`/`$(".dialog").dialog({...`

Comment: This solution works, but when I click on any button, all the dialog windows open (one over the other).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you are creating multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, where the `id` must be unique within a single `document`. Instead, use common classes on the `#trigger` and from there find the related `#dialog` to be shown. Try this:

```
<table class="table-hovered">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-left big">TITOLO</th>
        <th class="text-centered" align="center">
            <img src="img/w.png" width="35" height="35" title="wikipedia" align="middle"><br>
            wikipedia
        </th>
    </tr>
    <? while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    { ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-left"><?=$objResult["titolo"];?></td>
            <td class="text-centered">
                <button class="btn trigger">definizione</button>
                <div class="dialog" style="display: none;" title="definizione">
                    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="480" height="380" src="def.php?titolo=<?=$objResult['titolo'];?>"></iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?  } ?>
</table>
```

You can then assign a single event handler to the `.trigger` elements in either the `<head>` or just before `</body>`, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".trigger").click(function() {
            $(this).next('.dialog').dialog("open");
        });

        $(".dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            position: 'center' ,
            title: 'definizione',
            draggable: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 400, 
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            show: 'slide',
            hide: 'fade'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This procedure doesn't seem to work. When I click on the buttons, none opens a dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically like this (adding `<?=$objResult["titolo"];?>`to the `#trigger` IDs in the loop:

```
<td class="text-left"><?=$objResult["titolo"];?></td>
<td class="text-centered"><button id="trigger<?=$objResult["titolo"];?>" class="btn">definizione</button><div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title="definizione"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="480" height="380" src="def.php?titolo=<?=$objResult['titolo'];?>"></iframe></div></td>
<script>
$( "#trigger<?=$objResult["titolo"];?>" ).click(function() {
```

what I am not sure about is the use of the PHP "$" inside the jQuery script, that might require a bit more tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
$("tr:has(.trigger):has(.dialog)").each(function() {
      var row = this
      var dialog = $(".dialog", row).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        position: 'center',
        title: 'definizione',
        draggable: true,
        width: 480,
        height: 380,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        show: 'slide'
      });
      $(".trigger", row).click(function() {
        dialog.dialog("open");
      });

})
```