# jqueryui dialog inside php while loop not opening as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i want to show jquery dialog on link click but when i click multiple dialog are opening instead of one.

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241688/jquery-dialog-in-php-while-loop) but still not working.

if i use next() method then no dialog is opening as you can read in link above.

i think i should use data attribute but i don't know how to use it.

Here is my jqueryui dialog div content inside a php while loop:

```html
while ($rows8 = $sql8->fetch_assoc()){

 echo "<div id='view-reply'>

  <span class='report_link'><a data-myid='$rows8[reply_id]' class='rp' href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='img/admin.png' alt='report to admin' title='report to admin'/></a></span>
          
  <div style='display: none;' class='post_reply_report_win'>
   <h4><span>Report to Admin</span><hr/></h4>
   <form class='reportForm' method='post' action='report_process.php?uid=".urlencode(base64_encode($rows8['reply_by']))."&p=".urlencode(base64_encode($rows8['reply_to_post']))." '>
    <p><span>Subject</span><br/>
    <input type='text' name='reporttxt' maxlength='100' required autofocus /></p>
    <p><span>Details</span><br/>
    <textarea name='reportarea' maxlength='500' required ></textarea></p>
    <p><input type='submit' name='reportsub' id='sub' value='Submit'/></p>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
}
```

and i am displaying it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".post_reply_report_win").dialog({
       
  modal : true,
  draggable : false,
  resizable : false,
  autoOpen : false, 
  buttons: [
      { 
       text: "Cancel", 
       click: function () {  
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
       },
       style: "outline: none;" 
      }
     ],
  close : function(event, ui){
      $(this).dialog("close");
     }   
   
 });
  
  
  $("#view-reply .report_link a").click(function() { 
 
   $(".post_reply_report_win").dialog("open");
    
   return false;
 });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it myself after a long research.

i am posting my solution here just to help others that are also searching for the solution :)

**So here is the solution:**

*php:*

```html
while ($rows8 = $sql8->fetch_assoc()){

  echo "<span class='post_reply_report_link'><a data-myid='$rows8[reply_id]' class='rp' href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='img/admin.png' alt='report to admin' title='report abuse'/></a></span>
          
  <div class='post_reply_report_win_$rows8[reply_id]' id='post_reply_report_win' >
   <h4><span>Report Abuse</span><hr/></h4>
   <form class='post_reply_report_form' method='post' action='report_process.php?uid=".urlencode(base64_encode($rows8['reply_by']))."&p=".urlencode(base64_encode($rows8['reply_to_post']))." '>
    <p><span>Subject</span><br/>
    <input type='text' name='reporttxt' maxlength='100' required autofocus /></p>
    <p><span>Details</span><br/>
    <textarea name='reportarea' maxlength='500' required ></textarea></p>
    <p><input type='submit' name='reportsub' id='sub' value='Submit'/></p>
   </form>
  </div>";

}
```

*javascript:*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".post_reply_report_link a").click(function() { 
 
 var myID = $(this).attr("data-myid");
    
   $(".post_reply_report_win_"+myID).dialog({ 
    
    modal : true,
    draggable : false,
    resizable : false,
    buttons: [
        { 
         text: "Cancel", 
         click: function () {  
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
           },
         style: "outline: none;" 
        }
       ],
    close : function(event, ui){
        $(this).dialog("close");
       }   
    
 
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click listener simple opens them all as they do all have the class!

```
$(".post_reply_report_win").dialog("open");
```

You need to have unique identifiers for opening the dialog. Assignment can be done by class.
So I would go like this:

Give this line `<div style='display: none;' class='post_reply_report_win'>` a unique id like so `<div style='display: none;' class='post_reply_report_win' id='post_reply_report_dialog_<?echo $i;?>`';

$i would start at 1 and $i++ at the end in your loop.

your listener should then use .closest() from jquery to find the closest .post_reply_report_win element and get the id from that.
that id is the one you pass to your .open call of the dialog.

```
$('#'+$(this).closest('.post_reply_report_win').attr('id')).dialog("open");
```

Comment: @user220095 please post your coding again or update your coding from the original question

Answer (score 0):

The `id` should be unique. `id='view-reply'` is inside while loop and it is repeating.

Try below code:

```
 $(".report_link a").click(function() { 

          $(this).parent('.report_link').next('.post_reply_report_win').dialog("open");

          return false;
});
```